How can you test images on a page with playwright .NET without extra dependencies?
Say for example I need to test this page's images, what are my options in playwright for .NET? Is it possible to visually compare the page or image? Can you check if the src field in the  is correct?
The only resource I could find is this SO question, but I don't want to add more dependencies.

You will need to add more dependencies

This question is similar to: Take a screenshot and compare it with another image using playwright.net - C#. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@hardkoded, as written in the last sentence, I don't want to add more dependencies. Can I assume your response meant there is no other way?

You could write your own algorithm. You load both images and compare them manually.

As written in the comments by hardkoded, the only way I could find is to use third party dependencies or writing your own comparer. For solutions go to this SO page.
